# how to match non zero-padded digit in ruby using regexps?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regular expression that match exactly 1-12 and 1-31. 01 is not matched and 65 is not matched. For example "abc 6 abc" is a match, while "abc 65 "is not.

I try this `/[1-9]|1[012]/`, which does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  add word boundaries around your pattern . `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

For `1-12`

```
/\b(?:1[012]|[1-9])\b/
```

For `1-31`

```
\b(?:[12]\d|3[01]|[1-9])\b
```

Comment: I assume you could instead use a capture group, or add two `\b`'s and have no group. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is not a job for a single regexp. Would it not be hard to understand this code when you look back to it in a few years? Why not split it up in two parts?

```
my_string = 'abc 01 def'
my_string2 = 'abc 8 def'

p  ('1'..'12').include?(my_string[/\d+/])  #=> false
p  ('1'..'12').include?(my_string2[/\d+/]) #=> true
```